# SSIS error Error code: 0x00040EDA suddenly occurring after many months of success

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

I have an SSIS package that has been running since long before I arrived at my current position and it has suddenly started to fail.  Although I am not an expert with SSIS I did look at the view in SQL that for s_s_h_data source and see the MTGSIZE field is INT and in the s_s_h_Data Acess database the datatype is NUMBER (int).

I have read several posts saying that if you open the package, double click and edit the problem node in the business development studio it forces the package to re-read and will "fix itself"  This hasn't been my experience today.  I have search for hours, rebooted servers and can't seem to figure out which the issue is.  The table being transferred has about 2000 rows in it and it stops after the 7th row.  I have looked at the 7th and 8th records in the table and can see no anomalies with wither of them.  Since it got through 7 rows I doubt it is connection or security related

I have been trying to figure this out for over 6 hrs and I'm started to get frustrated.

Is there any light anyone can shed to point me in the right direction? below is the fell error I am getting.

Message
Executed as user: domain\sqlsvc. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
Started:  3:05:31 PM  Error: 2015-01-02 15:05:55.20
Code: 0xC0202009
Source: s_s_h_Data OLE DB Destination [1361]
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x00040EDA.  End Error
Error: 2015-01-02 15:05:55.20
Code: 0xC020901C
Source: s_s_h_Data OLE DB Destination [1361]
Description: There was an error with input column "MTGSIZE" (2036) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (1374). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".  End Error
Error: 2015-01-02 15:05:55.20
Code: 0xC0209029
Source: s_s_h_Data OLE DB Destination [1361]
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (1374)" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (1374)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error
Error: 2015-01-02 15:05:55.20
Code: 0xC0047022
Source: s_s_h_Data SSIS.Pipeline
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (1361) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (1374). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error
Error: 2015-01-02 15:05:55.20
Code: 0xC02020C4
Source: s_s_h_Data OLE DB Source [1346]
Description: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.  End Error
Error: 2015-01-02 15:05:55.20
Code: 0xC0047038
Source: s_s_h_Data SSIS.Pipeline
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "OLE DB Source" (1346) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error

DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  3:05:31 PM  Finished: 3:05:55 PM
Elapsed:  23.93 seconds.
The package execution failed.
The step failed.

**ADDING ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

After additional digging it appears that the "real" error is prior to the one listed in the "view history".  If I open the packed and click debug I see this error.

Information: 0x4004300A at s_s_h_Data, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x0 at Clear s_s_h_Data: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
Warning: 0x0 at Clear s_s_h_Data: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
Error: 0xC002F210 at Clear s_s_h_Data, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "Delete from s_s_h_Data" failed with the following error: "Could not delete from specified tables.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
Task failed: Clear s_s_h_Data
Warning: 0x80019002 at sData: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "sData.dtsx" finished: Failure.

Strange if I "test" the connection they DO work but if I try to execute the SQL task while debugging I get the error above.  This particular line is deleting data from an Access table and the next step it to insert data into the same table.  There are no specific permissions on the tables in the Access database even though it seems like it might be a permission thing.

Comment: "There was an error with input column "MTGSIZE" (2036) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (1374). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data." - too long, or wrong type of data....

Comment: I did see that which is why I made sure both fields where INTs. The largests number is just under 70k so I doubt it is an issue with INT vs BIGINT so what else could cause an error like that going from INT to NUMBER (access INT)  If it were a VARCHAR I'd get it

Comment: What day did it fail (check your SQL Agent logs). What data appeared on this day that might cause this error? Alter your select query to selectively ignore rows (using a where clause) until you find the row(s) causing the error.

Comment: I have added some more information.  I can no longer get the package to do a simple delete. The access datasource is the same as it has been for over a year so I even more confussed

Answer (score 0):

I will point out that the values allowed for Access int are much smaller than the values allowed for SQL Server int; they are more like small int.  So yes this error is entirely possible.

Comment: Thanks I did see that and I have change the access dbase to "Long Integer".  Please see the Addition info I posted in the question as I am now getting some different results when I run from BIDS/SSIS than when I run it from the SQL agent that runs the job

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Sahuagin it does answer the orginal issue brought up. I know when to post a comment and when I am answering.